# Intellij-Run Application which profile does it use?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, dependencies

In my POM I have two profiles, Dev and Prod but there's also dependencies not enclosed within those profiles.Does it mean that there's a **default** profile too?

When you do Run Application from within Intellij which profile does it use to run the app? the default,ther prod or the dev? Under the maven panel you can check a profile, Dev or Prod but you can also not check anything.Does this play a role when you do Run Application?

What is very strange is that in the default profile I exclude the embedded tomcat from spring-boot-starter,but still when I do run application it loads it!, while
`mvn dependncy:tree` shows that tomcat is not included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IntelliJ you can create multiple run configurations (it’s a dropdown next to the run button). Within a configuration you can specify the active profiles you want to use.